# Target img elemnt inside div through Jquery index

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Hi i'm trying to display star rating and i have HTML structure as mentioned below

```html
<div class="ImagesDetails"><div><img src="grey.png"/></div><div><img src="grey.png"/></div><div><img src="grey.png"/></div><div><img src="grey.png"/></div><div><img src="grey.png"/></div></div>
```

then i'll get rating value from ajax response.
Now i need to change star rating image from grey image to black image inside div's till that count through jquery as mentioned below.

```js
var rating = 3
```

```
<div class="ImagesDetails"><div><img src="black.png"/></div><div><img src="black.png"/></div><div><img src="black.png"/></div><div><img src="grey.png"/></div><div><img src="grey.png"/></div></div>
```

I'm getting index of particular div like this

```js
$('.ImagesDetails').eq(k).find('div').each(function(){
  var xyz = $(this).index();
});
```

Here k is index of ajax response. Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[:lt()](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)** selectors here:

> Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.

```
$('.ImagesDetails img:lt('+ rating  +')').attr("src","black.png")
```